# In relational database, how Keys are represented Internally in secondary storage device and In GUI.

Tags: database, key, storage, relational

Database keys are primary, candidate, and foreign. 
I have researched all about what these are and what relational database does.
But i'm not sure about this one. There's so many answers but i cannot figure which one will be correct.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- **Primary Key** Primary key is a set of one or more fields/columns of a
  table that uniquely identify a record in database table. It can not
  accept null, duplicate values. Only one Candidate Key can be Primary
  Key.
- **Candidate Key** A Candidate Key is a set of one or more fields/columns
  that can identify a record uniquely in a table. There can be multiple
  Candidate Keys in one table. Each Candidate Key can work as Primary
  Key. Example: In below diagram ID, RollNo and EnrollNo are Candidate
  Keys since all these three fields can be work as Primary Key.

[image]

- **Foreign Key**  Foreign Key is a field in database table that is Primary
  key in another table. It can accept multiple null, duplicate values.
  For more help refer the article [Difference between primary key and
  foreign key](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/TENc260912-Difference-between-Primary-Key-and-Foreign-Key.html). Example : We can have a DeptID column in the Employee
  table which is pointing to DeptID column in a department table where
  it a primary key.
- **Composite/Compound Key** Composite Key is a combination of more than
  one fields/columns of a table. It can be a Candidate key, Primary
  key.
- **Unique Key** Uniquekey is a set of one or more fields/columns of a
  table that uniquely identify a record in database table. It is like
  Primary key but it can accept only one null value and it can not have
  duplicate values. For more help refer the article [Difference between
  primary key and unique key.](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/V2bS260912-Difference-between-Primary-Key-and-Unique-Key.html)

For more refference: [SQL keys](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/GcF9120312-Different-Types-of-SQL-Keys.html)

Comment: Thanks , but how they are represented in GUI and Secondary storage device ?